# Blender Cloud addon won't open

Tags: interface, add-on, error

I am trying to use the Blender Cloud addon, but whenever I try to open it (via "Image>Get image from Blender Cloud", or via the shortcut "Shift+Ctrl+Alt+A") I get the following error message:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\blgri\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\blender_cloud\texture_browser\__init__.py", line 106, in invoke
self._draw_handle = context.space_data.draw_handler_add(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw_handler_add'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I have reset Blender to default (factory) settings, and the only two non-default addons I have enabled are:

- "System: Blender Cloud" (downloaded from https://cloud.blender.org/services, and installed without extracting from the .zip)
- "System: Blender ID authentication" (required for using the Blender Cloud addon)

Any help or direction where to look for help would be greatly appreciated

A screenshot of the addons:
[image: addon preferences]

A screenshot of the error:
[image: error message]

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same error in version 2.93.1. The addon installed from the same zip file works fine in Blender 2.83.

Comment: I was having this problem myself. I just installed 2.93.2 which was released yesterday and it now seems to work as expected.